# How to stay in the cmd window when the exception has been raised?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have written a programme by python which is successfully tested under eclipse.Then I used pyinstaller to excute it as a .exe file. When the programme raise the exception ,the cmd window will quit immediately. I want to stay in this window to take a good look at this exception. How can I do it ? Thank you.

Comment: can you open the terminal first and then run your program from there?

Comment: Yes,I can run my program if there is no exception happen.

Answer (score 0):

As Ms Turdy mentioned, you should run it in a command prompt or terminal first, if it will have the same behavior as the exe.

You can execute a python script with `python -m pdb script.py` and it will enter into the debugger. You run it by pressing `C` for continue, then it will break when it raises the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But I have test the program in the eclipse.And it's ok in that IDE.So I want to put it into the .exe by pyinstaller.I want to the .exe throw the exception ,because I have writen some intention in the exception in order to warn the users.But the window closed so rapidly when the exception has been throwed.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the python script has finished its job. You can do this:

```
import time

# your code
...

time.sleep(20)
```

This will give you 20 seconds to see the result. And after 20 s, the cmd window will remain 20 s for you to see the result. You can change the time for your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But it happens when the programme throw the exception.I have added the time.sleep in my code ,but it has less effect.

Comment: @user3093493 If the program throws a exception, you should just run the script in IDLE or some interpreters else to find the reason instead of running the exe. After you confirming your code is right, then use pyinstaller. Or you can log the information where the exception may occurs in your code. And take your step of packaging program into consideration, because I have failed in packaging the python scripts for some times.

Comment: Thank you.Yes , my program has been tested under the eclipse,so I want to use pyinstaller to publish it.And when the exception has raised,there will be some warnings for users which I has writen in the exception part.The problem is the warning stay for a short time before the window closed.

Comment: @user3093493 If you want to show the warnings for users, and your program do not have a GUI, you can just log them in a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `raw_input` to hold the screen:

```
import traceback
try:
    # do something dangerous
except Exception, e:
    print 'Error:', e
    print traceback.format_exc()
    raw_input('Input anything to end...')
```